# How to insert font-awesome icons in MathJax?

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome, mathjax

I want to write a formular with [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathjax.html) where I use a [font-awesome icon](http://fontawesome.io/) as a replacement for an mathematical symbol.

If I try something like

```
$$6 \cdot <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> + 5 \cdot <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>$$
```

I get

[image]

Is there an easy way to get font-awesome icons integrated in MathJax?

Comment: It's not possible in the way you've tried it. As a workaround you could use images instead of font-awesome icons with [this mathjax extension](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions/tree/master/img)

Answer (score 2):

If you can ensure an HTML-based output, you can use MathJax's non-standard `\class{classname}{math}` macro as below.

**Note** that this won't work in the SVG output (without additional hacks anyway).

```js
script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

<h1>Using fontawesome in math</h1>

$$ f: \class{fa fa-twitter}{} \to \class{fa fa-home}{}$$
```